# Need Script for connecting cassandra with password and execute CQL using python

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I need a script for which i need to connect CassDb nodes with password using python script

I tried bellow script

```
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ap = PlainTextAuthProvider(username='##',password='##')
cass_contact_points=['cassdb01.p01.eng.sjc01.com', 'cassdb02.p01.eng.sjc01.com']
cluster = Cluster(cass_contact_points,auth_provider=ap,port=50126)
session = cluster.connect('##')
```

I'm getting bellow error:

```
File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\cassandra\cluster.py", line 2792, in _reconnect_internal
raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.44.67.92': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None'), '10.44.67.91': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None')})
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential problems.

First, unless you're in a upgrade scenario or you've had past problems with protocol versions, I would *not* specify that.  The driver should negotiate that value.  Setting it to `2` will fail with Cassandra 3.x, for example.

Second, I don't think the driver can properly parse-out ports from the endpoints.

```
node_ips = ['cassdb01.p01.eng.sjc01.com:50126', 'cassdb02.p01.eng.sjc01.com:50126']
```

When I pass the port along with my endpoints, I get a similar failure.  So I would try changing that line to this:

```
node_ips = ['cassdb01.p01.eng.sjc01.com', 'cassdb02.p01.eng.sjc01.com']
```

Try starting with that.  I have some other thoughts, but let's get those two obvious settings out of the way.